# Chrome Extensions - Copy Link Google Search

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome Extension which places a button next to the link on a Google Search and when pressed it will copy the link to the clipboard. However I am not able to get it working.

Here is the Manifest File.

```
{
 "content_scripts":[
{
  "all_frames":false,
  "js":[ "js/jquery.min.js", "js/jquery-ui.min.js" "js/script.js" ],
  "matches":[ "https://www.google.com.au/*" ],
  "run_at":"document_end"
}
],
"description":"Copies link to the clipboard.",
"icons":{
"16":"img/icon-16.png",
"32":"img/icon-32.png",
"64":"img/icon-64.png",
"128":"img/icon-128.png",
"256":"img/icon-256.png",
"512":"img/icon-512.png"
},
"manifest_version":2,
"minimum_chrome_version":"40",
"name":"Copy Link",
"version":"0.1",
"version_name":"0.1 beta"
}
```

Here is the Script File.

```
  function copy() {
   var h = $("a[href]");
   h.document.execCommand('copy');
   $("button").after(h);
  }
  $(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified", copy);
```

Here is an inspected element from a search result.

```
  <h3 class="r">
   <a href="http://www.speedtest.net/">Speedtest.net by Ookla - The Global   Broadband Speed Test</a>
  </h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `document.execCommand` is not allowed in content script. Only `background.html` and `popup.html` are allowed clipboard access. If you want to copy anything in the content script, you have to send the data to background with [MessagePassing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) of chrome.

Comment: Oh ok, could you send an example or a link to a reference document? Thanks :)

Comment: Find more details on the chromium posts: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395376